# Laravel orderby query with distinct

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm trying to get unique thread_id with latest order by desc created_time

This is my table sample.

```
===========================================
= id = thread_id = page_id = created_time =
===========================================
= 1  = 3         = 1       = 1551162660   =
= 2  = 1         = 1       = 1551162661   =
= 3  = 1         = 1       = 1551162662   =
= 4  = 2         = 1       = 1551162663   =
= 5  = 3         = 1       = 1551162664   =
= 6  = 1         = 1       = 1551162665   =
===========================================
```

This is my code.

```
DB::table('table_a')->select('thread_id')->orderBy('created_time', 'desc')->where('page_id', $page_id)->distinct()->get();
```

The problem with my code now is, it skips the latest created_time because of the distinct..

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Please print your query using toSql() and update you querstion.

Comment: `DB::raw("SELECT thread_id, MAX(created_time) FROM table_a GROUP BY thread_id");`

Answer (score 3):

try using a group by instead of `distinct`

```
DB::table('table_a')
 ->select('thread_id')
 ->orderBy('created_time', 'desc')
 ->where('page_id', $page_id)
 ->groupBy('thread_id')
 ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest() method for that.

```
DB::table('table_a')->latest('created_time')->distinct()->get();
```

Edit: If you still have issues you can use the groupBy() method as well.

[Official documentation at the Laravel Docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: Create a question for you specific problem, 'Not works to me' doesn't explain what's happening. I can't help you with only this information.

Comment: @Kerel , latest is functionally equivalent to the orderBy in the original question. That is why it doesn't work for Pablo.

`public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
} `

Comment: Pedro didn't post anything so how do you know what he is trying to do?

Comment: this is no different than using `where`, it will still give you the same error if you use `latest`